# uWSGI logging not working if log file is removed

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, catalyst

My goal is rotating the logs generated by uWSGI, but when the original log file is deleted (after compression) it is not re-created again.

So I thought that the app needs a graceful restart of the master process after the file is deleted. I use this RESTART script:

```
/home/tester/uwsgi-18
--reload /var/run/uwsgi/my_app_tester/my_app_tester.pid
```

The app restart, but the log does not.

To get the logging work again I need to kill -2 the process and run the START script again, so another process number is generated and the logging works again.

Obviously I do not want such hard STOP just for rotating logs...

My app is built with Catalyst, the server runs Nginx and here it is the uWSGI START script:

```
/home/tester/uwsgi-18
--master
--daemonize /var/log/uwsgi/my_app_tester/log
--socket /tmp/uwsgi/my_app_tester/my_app_tester.socket
--processes 1
--psgi /home/tester/my_app/my_app.psgi
--pidfile /var/run/uwsgi/my_app_tester/my_app_tester.pid
--procname-master TESTER
-L
```

Is there another way to restart the app without loosing connections and logging?

Thank you in advance:
Migue

Comment: This might help:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510174/uwsgi-logrotate-not-working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510174/uwsgi-logrotate-not-working

Comment: That post is about an error with the file rotation itself, just in case that there is no file. My problem is with uWSGI that do not recreate log unless I do a full hard STOP and then a START

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have various approaches:

1) copytruncate in the logrotate script, this will work reliably and without the help of uWSGI

2) uWSGI log rotation: `--log-maxsize <bytes>` will automatically rotate logs when a specific size is reached

3) classic logrotation + log reloading, just add `--log-master` and trigger log reloading with http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/MasterFIFO.html

There are other approaches too (like triggering the log reopen when touching a files), but the previous one are the most common.

Comment: Options 1 and 2 works well. No sure about 3, but I prefer reading about it before testing. Thanks!

Comment: Picked option 1 because `--log-maxsize` feels less clear and convenient.